# Angular5 - newly created object from class is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular5

i have a service class where i am passing an object from component saving it temporarily model class. i want to get the $key in lecturer.service.ts from lecturer.ts (Model).

**lecturer.component.ts**

```
onItemClick(lec: Lecturer) {
  this.lecturerService.selectedLecturer = Object.assign({},lec); // this is working properly as i have seen in console.log(lec)
}
```

**lecturer.ts**

```
export class Lecturer {
    $key: string;
    userName: string;
    userEmail: string;
    userProfileImageUrl: string;
}
```

now i just want the $key from lecture.ts in service class but somehow i cannot get the key to use in this function..

**lecture.service.ts**

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { Lecturer } from './lecturer';
 import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from '@angular/fire/database';

 @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
 })

  export class LecturerService {
     lecturerList: AngularFireList<any>;
     assignedCourseList: AngularFireList<any>;

     selectedLecturer: Lecturer = new Lecturer();

     constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

     getAssignedCourse() {
     this.assignedCourseList = this.db.list('Users/' + this.selectedLecturer.$key + '/Course'); //this is where i'm having problem to get the $key
       console.log(this.selectedLecturer.$key);
       return this.assignedCourseList;
     }
  }
```

what can i do to achieve this.. ?

Comment: I guess you have undefined value in this.selectedLecturer.$key. console the this.selectedLecturer.

Comment: yes i have unidentified value. but what is the way of getting the value. i also tried like this,  
               this.selectedLecturer['$key']
which also did not work..

Comment: You are just making an empty object of lecturer as selectedLecturer. You have to assign an object to that

Comment: this.lecturerService.selectedLecturer = Object.assign({},lec); I think i did it in my lecturer.component.ts like this where the console is showing all the values. but i can't get it in the lecturer.service.ts

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

*I think you should pass the default value to it like this ...*

**lecturer.ts file**

```
export class Lecturer {
   $key: string = '';
   userName: string = '';
   userEmail: string = '';
   userProfileImageUrl: string = '';
}
```

**new Object creation**

```
selectedLecturer: Lecturer = new Lecturer();

console.log(selectedLecturer)
// output will be
 { $key: '',
   userName: '',
   userEmail:'',
   userProfileImageUrl:''
 }
```

**Solution 2:**

**lecture.ts file**

*Or add a constructor to assign value while creating a new object like this...*

```
export class Lecturer {
   $key: string;
   userName: string;
   userEmail: string;
   userProfileImageUrl: string;
   constructor(key:string,userName: string,userEmail: string, userProfileImageUrl: string){
         this.$key = key;
         this.userName = userName;
         this.userEmail = userEmail;
         this.userProfileImageUrl = userProfileImageUrl
        }
}
```

**new Object creation**

```
selectedLecturer: Lecturer = new Lecturer('my_key','name','email','url');

console.log(selectedLecturer)
// output will be
 { $key: 'my_key',
   userName: 'name',
   userEmail:'email',
   userProfileImageUrl:'url'
 }
```

Comment: really thank you for the suggestion. but it did not work. :(

Comment: Okay, there must be another problem. But this is the standard way for class-based object creation.

Comment: btw from where are you calling getAssignedCourse() function??

Comment: i get that. actually i was able to do the same while fetching the data from the selectedLecturer in a form from other module using this, though i used two way binding i somehow thought this would work to. but this is not working. 
i was calling it from assignedcourse.module.ts .